# Finding the area bounded by some curves using change of variables and double integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, change-of-variable, jacobian

find the area of the first-quadrant region bounded by the curves $y = x^3,y=2x^3,x=y^3,x=4y^3$ be the curves that bound the area:

[image]

now we can use the substitution:

$$y =ux^3$$
$$x =vy^3$$

in order to find the jacobian we have to express x and y in terms of u and v hence:

$$y = \frac{1}{u^{1/8}v^{3/8}}$$
$$x = \frac{1}{u^{3/8}v^{1/8}}$$

now we can find the Jacobian:

$$\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = \frac{9}{64u^{3/4}v^{3/4}} - \frac{1}{64u^{5/4}v^{5/4}}$$

hence the area must be:

$$\int \int \Big|\frac{9}{64u^{3/4}v^{3/4}} - \frac{1}{64u^{5/4}v^{5/4}} \Big| dudv$$

Am I going on the right path?

I have trouble finding the limits of integration. by the way the book answer is:

$$\frac{1}{8}(2-\sqrt{2})$$

Comment: any questions...?

Comment: Yes - why didn't you just edit the original post? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4750951/problem-finding-the-area-bounded-by-some-curves

Comment: @SeanRoberson because it was closed

Comment: You can still edit it and the community can vote to reopen.

Comment: Your Jacobian determinant is not correct. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=jacobian+x%3D%28u%5E3v%29%5E%28-1%2F8%29%2C+y%3D%28uv%5E3%29%5E%28-1%2F8%29+with+respect+to+%28u%2Cv%29)

Comment: @user170231 thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the bounds we want $y^3\leq x\leq 4y^3$ and $x^3\leq y\leq 2x^3$ where $u=y/x^3$ and $v=x/y^3$, so $$1\leq v\leq 4\\1\leq u\leq 2$$

---

Also $$\begin{align}x&= u^{-3/8}v^{-1/8}\\y&=u^{-1/8}v^{-3/8}\\\mathrm J &= \begin{Vmatrix} -(3/8)u^{-11/8}v^{-1/8} &-(1/8)u^{-3/8}v^{-9/8}\\ -(1/8)u^{-9/8}v^{-3/8} & -(3/8)u^{-1/8}v^{-11/8}\end{Vmatrix}\\&=(1/64)\lvert (9-1) u^{-12/8} v^{-12/8} \rvert\\&=(1/8)\lvert u^{-3/2} v^{-3/2} \rvert
\end{align}$$

Comment: What about the double integral? and the area of the region?

Comment: is the double integral correct?

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts  No.  Your Jacobian determinant is awry.